# TypeError: 'dict' does not Support the Buffer Interface

Tags: python, dictionary, binary, python-3.4, binaryfiles

I've looked on stack overflow for an answer, but they all seem to be `str` or `list` or `int` not supported by the buffer interface, whereas my problem is with `dict` not being supported. What should I do? Can a dictionary not be copied to a **.bin** binary file? If the solution is complex (or involving modules) could you please explain to me what to do as I am new to programming.

May I also add, I cannot use external modules (i.e. `numPy` or `sciPy`) as I am on a work computer without permissions to install modules. I do believe there is a fix to this using the Standard Library, I just don't what what it is.

I am using Python 3.4

```
#my code
def writeBinary():
    myFile = open('books.bin','wb') #open binary file
    book = {'Title': ' ', #create empty dictionary with keys and no values
            'ISBN': ' ',
            'Price': ' ',
            'Year Of Publication': ' '}
    end = False
    while end != True:
        option = input("Enter 'Y' to enter book details, or 'N' to quit: ")
        if option == 'Y':
            title = input("Enter the title of the book: ") #input data
            book['Title'] = title #assign input data to dictionary keys
            ISBN = input("Enter the ISBN of the book: ")
            book['ISBN'] = ISBN
            price = float(input("Enter the price of the book: £"))
            book['Price'] = price
            yearOfPublication = int(input("Enter the books year of publication: "))
            book['Year Of Publication'] = yearOfPublication
            myFile.write(book) #write dictionary to binary file
            print(book) #to see the current contents of the dictionary
        elif option == 'N':
            print("Input terminated.")
            end = True
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Please try again.")
    myFile.close() #close binary file

writeBinary()
```

Comment: you have to serialize your dictionary using pickle or json.

Comment: ^^ as I already told you on the question you deleted. Without more context, what else do you expect? This isn't a code-writing service; read up on the relevant modules and at least *try* something yourself.

Comment: That's the same code, with the same problem, you had earlier. There is no effort there to serialise the dictionary before writing it to the file, despite me telling you, as Jean-François just has, that's what you needed to do. So what, if anything, did you *learn* from your research? If you want a link, to save you all of that effort googling "Python JSON": https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html. See also CSV, pickle, ...

Comment: Although i didn't find my answer, i did learn a lot about pickling data and the alternatives when saving files. For example the `pickle` module, but not much more than that; maybe a little `json` and `simplejson`, but it wasn't clear enough to me to put into practise. Thank you @jonsharpe and @Jean-François Fabre for clearing things up for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot write a dictionary on a file like that.

You have to serialize the dictionary, for instance using `json` (or `pickle`):

```
import json
myFile.write(json.dumps(book))
```

Or directly (`myFile` must be open in `w` mode, not `wb`):

```
json.dump(book,myFile)
```

Then reload it using

```
with open('books.bin',"r") as myFile:
    book = json.load(myFile)
```

`json` has the advantage over `pickle`: serialized file can be edited by hand since it's text. But takes more diskspace (unless zipped).

Comment: Thasnk you for the answer, but i get an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'` strangest thing is, it happened on line 184 (`line 184, in dump fp.write(chunk)`) and my program is only 32 lines long. Strange!

Comment: [dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage) takes a [file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) not a filename.

Comment: sorry, you have to pass a file handle, not a file name. See my edit.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! Am i right in saying that the `with` syntax automatically closes the file, so `myFile.close()` is not required?